ASP.NET Core 8.0 Web API : cors issue when using CMS (Terminal Four)
I built an ASP.NET Core 8.0 Web API which works fine in Google script and from a web site built from notepad. However  when I am trying to communicate with it from a content management system (terminal four), it throws a CORS error

Access to fetch at 'https://a.someting.edu/Newsletter/api/newsletter' from origin 'https://t4.something.edu' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status

I am just trying to do a POST and I'm stumped why this would work with Google script and a vanilla site but not a site housed in a CMS?
My Program.cs file:
var MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                      policy =>
                      {
                          policy.WithOrigins("https://t4.something.edu")
                                .AllowAnyHeader()
                                .AllowAnyMethod();
                      });
});

builder.Services.AddControllers();

// context 
IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .AddCommandLine(args)
    .AddUserSecrets<Program>(true)
    .Build();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<NewsletterContext>(option =>
{
    option.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
});

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddTransient<IApiKeyValidation, ApiKeyValidation>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ApiKeyAuthFilter>();

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

Terminal Four Content Management System
<script>
        function send() 
        {
            var url = 'https://a.something.edu/News/api/news';
            var headers = {
                    'X-API-Key' : "something1234",
                    'Accept': "application/json",
                    'Content-Type': "application/json;charset=utf-8"
            };
            var data = {
                    "email" : document.getElementById("customerEmail").value
            };
            
            var payload = JSON.stringify(data);
            
            var options = {
                method: "POST",
                headers: headers,
                body: payload
            };
            
            try {
                var response = fetch(url, options);
            }catch(error) {
                alert('Error is : ' + error);
            }
            alert('Response is - ' + response);
        }
</script>

I tried to set the mode to no-cors, however that results in an unsupported media type error 415.
Included in my program.cs file is cors middleware that I found on Microsoft learn cors, same issue and am not sure I set that up correctly as I still have to set the response header on the web server to Access-Control-Allow-Origin = *. Which is verified by the web.config file:
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>

Not sure what else I can try or even where to look for the Web API to work as intended?
Update
Controller code
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
 [ApiController]
 public class NewsletterController(NewsletterContext context) : ControllerBase
 {
     private readonly NewsletterContext _context = context;

     [HttpPost]
     public async Task<ActionResult<NewsletterItem>> PostNewsletterItem(NewsletterItem newsletterItem)
     {
        _context.Newsletter_Emails.Add(newsletterItem);

         try
         {
             await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

         }
         catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
         {
            throw;
         }
         return Ok("The record has been saved correctly");
     }
 }

Update
Model code
namespace NewsletterEmails.Models
{
   public class NewsletterItem
   {
       [Key]
       public required string Email { get; set; }
    }
}


Hows your controller looks like, it seems controller action signature doesn't matched with the request pattern.

"https://something.edu" != "https://t4.something.edu"

@MdFaridUddinKiron Please see updated controller code above. Not sure what an action signature is?

By action signature I meant, method signature, means the type of parameter or model it accept, because 415 method not or request not allowed. So need to check if the method httpVerb and newsletterItem model is in valid format.

@MdFaridUddinKiron Please see updated model code above. Forgive me as I am still learning how to put together an API. What is the method of httpVerb?
